# Can't import (SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module)

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless, sam

Im building my first Lambda function, and wants to do it locally. So I have naturally installed SAM to do so.

From what I understand, AWS recently pushed a new version that would allow ES6 syntax with import/export and so on. But this is not the case for me, when I try to 'import' at the top of my handler-file, I'm getting this error:

`sam local invoke -e ./lambda/lambda_event.json LambdaDemoFunction`:

```
Skip pulling image and use local one: public.ecr.aws/sam/emulation-nodejs14.x:rapid-1.37.0-x86_64.

Mounting /Users/oakleaf/Work/Git/LCMSLambdaDispatcher/Lambda as /var/task:ro,delegated inside runtime container
START RequestId: d222a7f3-580f-4464-80fb-88a373d2ea09 Version: $LATEST
2022-02-14T21:51:58.695Z        undefined       ERROR   Uncaught Exception      {"errorType":"Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError","errorMessage":"SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module","stack":["Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module","    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:200:13)","    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:242:17)","    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)","    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)","    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)","    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)","    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)","    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)","    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"]}
qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
Function 'LambdaDemoFunction' timed out after 3 seconds
No response from invoke container for LambdaDemoFunction
```

My template.yaml in my root:

```
  LambdaDemoFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: Lambda/ # format is projectPath/
      Handler: lambda.lambdaHandler #format is filename.functionName
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
```

and then, inside /lambda/sdk I have a file called "Dispatcher.mjs" (Have also tried with "Dispatcher.js")

that contains:

```
export default class Dispatcher
{
    constructor()
    {

    }

    echo()
    {
        return "HEj hej från dispatcher";
    }
}
```

And lastly, my handler-file:

```
import { Dispatcher } from "./sdk/Dispatcher";

exports.lambdaHandler = async event => {
    return "hola";
};
```

I also have a package.json-file but is it even used right now? Im not sure, since I have not used npm or anything. It contains (among other things) "type": "module".

Any idea what I can do here to be able to use import/export properly, es6 style, in my Lambda?

**From the docs:** https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-node-js-es-modules-and-top-level-await-in-aws-lambda/